# jQuery: Hiding a menu with click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js

I am struggling with an issue regarding these mouseover/out events. There is an element I click on and it should open up a menu near the cursor (works). After clicking the element it should disapear (doesn't work). It's a combination of d3js and jQuery.

Maybe you have a far better approach which doesn't come up with this problems.

**jQuery handling the click Event**

```
$(".btcaccount").click(function(evt){
  $(".btcaction").css({
    top: evt.pageY+1,
    left: evt.pageX+1
  }).show();
});
```

- .btcaccount: the clickable element
- .btcaction: the menu which appears

**jQuery handling the mouseout event**

```
$(".btcaction").click(function(evt){
  $(this).css({
    display: none
   });
});
```

**Some HTML**

```
<ul class="btcaction">
  <li>Actions
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Action 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Action 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**d3js - .btcaccount class**

```
var circle = svg.append("g").selectAll("circle")
    .data(force.nodes())
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 10)
    .attr("class", "btcaccount")
    .call(force.drag);
```

**EDIT**
Under JsFiddle it somehow doesn't run but I included all code :-(

[JsFiddle Code](https://jsfiddle.net/k1yqLbsh/1/)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: `After clicking the element it should disappear` ? disappear what ? menu or button ? because you are calling `$($this).css` instead of `$(this).css`

Comment: Change `$this` to just `this` in: `$($this).css({
    display: none
   });`...and should work

Comment: the menu which has been previously clicked should disappear.

Comment: Question doesn't make sense. You mention hovering events and show code for click. Provide demo that reproduces whatever problem you have

Comment: Also, enclose `display` and `none` in quotation marks

Comment: @charlietfl well i click on an element which is some kind of circle. this invokes a menu where a user should be able to choose between actions. after clicking on one of these actions the menu should disappear and I will figure out how to do some action behind the click.

Comment: FYI `$(this).hide()` does same thing as `$(this).css({ display: 'none' });`

Comment: The jsFiddle is saying that it doesn't recognise the `force` method brought in by d3.js. I am unsure why as you seem to be implementing it correctly

Answer (score 0):

Somehow you have to include the hiding into the click-context. It works by now. Thanks for your suggestions!

```
// click on account
$(".btcaccount").click(function(evt){
  $(".btcaction").css({
    top: evt.pageY+1,
    left: evt.pageX+1
  }).show();

  // action menue
  $(".btcaction").click(function(){
  $(this).hide();

  });
});
```